# Sharepoint Picture library issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

on my home page, i have an existing picture library, which runs a slide show.
this works fine.

i tried too add a 2nd slide show, edit the web part to reference the 2nd picture library.  but when it loads, its loads the 1st picture library.

If i change the picture library on the 1st slideshow, it changes them on both!
very strange, can you advise?
thanks!
Using sharepoint 2013 foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be a known issue in Sharepoint 2013. You could have multiple slideshow webparts on a page in 2010, but this will not work in 2013. I have the same result when I test it in my Sharepoint 2013 environment.